# PDE: : example of finding particular integral

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, self-learning

[image]

When we look at the solution part, there is a statement **The PI of the given PDE is obtained as follows**

After the statement, I don't really understand all of the calculation. Especially, After the fourth line, I am stuck.  please explain what did the writer do?

Comment: I think this is a Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^{-1}$, which for the first two terms is $1-x$. In your case, $$x = \frac{3D'}{D} + \frac{2D'^2}{D^2}.$$

Comment: Please can you write a bit more explicit Dear @Fantini

Comment: Things in the form $(1+x)^{-1}$, assuming $|x| < 1$ for real numbers, have the expansion as a Taylor series given by $$\frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n.$$ He seemingly applied the same idea to the expression $$\left[ 1 + \left( 3 \frac{D'}{D} + 2 \frac{D'^2}{D^2} \right) \right]^{-1}.$$ I cannot attest it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They consider the solution of the pde

$$ Lu(x,y)=f(x,y). $$

So, $CF$ stands for solution of $Lu=0$ and
$PI$ the particular solution for $Lu=f$, then adding the
Solutions to get the general solution,
since $L$ is a linear operator. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306250/solve-u-xx-3u-xt-4u-tt-0-where-ux-0-x2-and-u-tx-0-ex/306312#306312) for a related technique.

**Added:** I think what they mean by $D$ is $\frac{d}{dx}$, $D'$ is $\frac{d}{dy}$, $\frac{1}{D^2}$ or ($D^{-2}$) is the second integral w.r.to $x$. Now,

> $$ \frac{1}{D^2}\left(1-3\frac{D'}{D}-...\right)(x+y)= \frac{1}{D^2}\left( (x+y)-\frac{D'}{D}(x+y)-... \right)$$
>
> $$=\frac{1}{D^2}\left( (x+y)-\frac{1}{D}(1)-0-0-... \right). $$
>
> $$ \implies\frac{1}{D^2}\left(x+y-\frac{3}{D}(1)\right) = \frac{1}{D^2}(x+y-3x)=\frac{1}{D^2}(y-2x)=y\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}  $$

Comment: Well, why omitted the -$2\frac{D'^2}{D^2}$ and wrote the minus sign?

Comment: I know, I want too many things, but I am not really understand. Please explain it on my example:(

Comment: Espacially how to get $\frac{1}{D^2}[y-2y]$ from the previous equation?

Comment: $\frac{3}{D}(1)=2x$ how to equal each other?

Comment: I dont really understand all of the equation. Please explain step by step:(

Comment: @B11b: I added more material.